# Little integration question about $\int_0^b dx\sqrt{2m(E+V_0\operatorname{sech}^2(x/a))}$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Does anyone see the connection between 
$$\int_0^b dx\sqrt{2m(E+V_0\operatorname{sech}^2(x/a))}$$
with $b=a~\text{arccosh}\left(\sqrt{-\dfrac{V_0}{E}}\right)$ and an integral of the form $$\int_0^Adu\frac{\sqrt{A^2-u^2}}{1+u^2}$$

I've tried plenty of substitutions but haven't been able to find the right one.

Answer (score 0):

$b=a\text{arccosh}\left(\sqrt{-\dfrac{V_0}{E}}\right)$ then $\cosh^2\dfrac{b}{a}=-\dfrac{V_0}{E}$ and $\sinh^2\dfrac{b}{a}=\cosh^2\dfrac{b}{a}-1=\dfrac{-E-V_0}{E}=A^2$

Let $x=at$ then
\begin{align}
\sqrt{2m\left(E+\dfrac{V_0}{\cosh^2\frac{x}{a}}\right)}
&= \sqrt{2m}\dfrac{\sqrt{E\cosh^2t+V_0}}{\cosh t}\\
&= \sqrt{2m}\dfrac{\sqrt{E+V_0+E\sinh^2t}}{\cosh t}\\
&= \sqrt{-2mE}\dfrac{\sqrt{-\frac{E+V_0}{E}-\sinh^2t}}{\cosh^2t}\cosh t\\
&= \sqrt{-2mE}\dfrac{\sqrt{A^2-\sinh^2t}}{1+\sinh^2t}\cosh t
\end{align}
where $A=\sinh\dfrac{b}{a}$. Now let substitution $\sinh t=u$ in the integral.